# Тире с двух сторон при приложении

Tags: пунктуация

У Розенталя говорится:

*Примечание. Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:
6) если приложение поясняет другое приложение: Все мы, воспитатели — учителя и родители, — должны учитывать возрастные особенности в общении с детьми;*

Не мог бы кто-нибудь прояснить данный момент: здесь приложение отделено тире с обеих сторон...
Что же, пункт некорректен, противоречит сам себе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В оригинальном справочнике Розенталя (1959) не так:
Тире для выделения (отделения) обособленных приложений употребляется в следующих случаях:
6) Если приложение поясняет другое обособленное приложение. Например:
*В книге рассказывается о жизни Паскаля, известного французского ученого — математика и физика.

Всем нам, воспитателям — учителям и вожатым, — всегда следует учитывать возрастные особенности в работе с детьми.*

Очевидно, что в том справочнике (где вы читали) неправильно отредактировали.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Не подскажете, у Вас веб-версия справочника или же физическая? Если электронная, не могли бы поделиться источником?